# How to use the @nuxtjs/axios module with Nuxt3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I have this code to get API data from https://fakestoreapi.com/products/

```html
<template>
<div>


</div>
</template>


  <script>  
  definePageMeta({
    layout: "products"
  })

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      data: '',
    }
  },
  async fetch() {
    const res = await this.$axios.get('https://fakestoreapi.com/products/')
    console.log(res.data)
  },
}
</script>
```

I have installed axios and in `nuxt.config.ts` I have:

```js
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({

    app: {
        head: {
            title: 'Nuxt',
            meta: [
                { name: 'description', content: 'Everything about - Nuxt-3'}
            ],
            link: [
                {rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons' }
            ]
        }
    },
    runtimeConfig: {
        currencyKey: process.env.CURRENCY_API_KEY
    },
    modules: [
        "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss",
    ],
    buildModules: [
        "@nuxtjs/axios"
    ],
    axios: {
      baseURL: '/',
    }
})
```

I have the following in my console

> is an experimental feature and its API will likely change.

I am not getting API data in the console.

Comment: Build Modules are deprecated as far as I know, move it to regular `modules` section. Also, the suspense thing is a warning should not cause any error so far. Set the value to your `data` state and check your Vue devtools to see if something is wrong. Otherwise, please provide a [repro] or a public Github repo.

Comment: @kissu https://github.com/AzizxonZufarov/newsnuxt/blob/main/pages/products/index.vue Please visit github repo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As told [on this page](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/), we don't use the `@nuxtjs/axios` module anymore with Nuxt3 but rather `ohmyfetch`, which is now baked-in directly in the core of the framework through `$axios` as [writted here](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/data-fetching/#usefetch).

Hence, your config file should look like this

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  app: {
    head: {
      title: 'Nuxt Dojo',
      meta: [
        { name: 'description', content: 'Everything about - Nuxt-3' }
      ],
      link: [
        { rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons' }
      ]
    }
  },
  runtimeConfig: {
    currencyKey: process.env.CURRENCY_API_KEY
  },
  modules: [
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss"
  ],
})
```

And the given `/pages/products/index.vue` can be like that

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <p v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">ID: {{ user.id }}  {{ user.name }}</p>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
definePageMeta({
  layout: "products"
})

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      users: '',
    }
  },
  async mounted() {
    this.users = await $fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  },
}
</script>
```

This is how it looks at the end (with a successful HTTP request in the network tab)

[image]

---

As a confirmation, we can see that the module is indeed not supported (and will not be) by Nuxt3 on the [modules page](https://nuxt.com/modules?q=axios&version=3.x).

The `Suspense` error is detailed in the [official documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/suspense.html#suspense)

> `<Suspense>` is an experimental feature. It is not guaranteed to reach stable status and the API may change before it does.

It may seem scary but you can totally use the API as per se and since it's a warning and not an error, it's totally fine!

Comment: That's great. Thanks but one question how can I do : limit the data count, order by desc/asc, sortby date with $fetch? When I use axios it has built-in features, but does $fetch has this kinda features? if yes, please give an example or link for reading. Thanks!

Comment: @AzizxonZufarov Nuxt3 have plenty of helpers like `useAsyncFetch` with various options that could help you with that (based on [`ohmyfetch`](https://github.com/unjs/ofetch)). Also, I never saw that [`axios`](https://github.com/axios/axios) could do such things since it's not its purpose. You can always create a composable with the desired behavior and some `sort/fliter/map/etc` array methods of yours if Nuxt3 doesn't [have enough](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-async-data#params) already.

Answer (score 0):

With nuxtjs3 I prefer to use a composable, it is flexible and self-imported throughout the app.

`composables/useApi.ts`

```js
import axios from 'axios'

export const useApi = () => {
  const baseURL = 'https://BASE_URL.com'
  const storeUser = useStoreUser()

  return axios.create({
    baseURL,
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${storeUser.token}`
    }
  })
}
```

Now what I do is simply

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>
const api = useApi()

const { data } = await api({
    method: 'get',
    url: '/auth/login'
})
</script>
```

Comment: You can probably skip `axios` in 2023, Nuxt has better defaults baked-in.

Comment: It's not better. You can't even change the default base_url