# ERROR Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'options') in Nuxt3

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I am getting this error when trying to create a Nuxt 3 application.  I haven't done anything with Axios yet and the application is essentially empty other than the boiler plate code.

```
(base) app % npx nuxi build
Nuxi 3.0.0                                                                             14:32:27
Nuxt 3.0.0 with Nitro 1.0.0                                                            14:32:27

 ERROR  Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'options')                        14:32:28

  at axiosModule (node_modules/@nuxtjs/axios/lib/module.js:12:13)
  at installModule (node_modules/@nuxt/kit/dist/index.mjs:416:9)
  at async initNuxt (node_modules/nuxt/dist/index.mjs:1825:7)
  at async loadNuxt (node_modules/nuxt/dist/index.mjs:1857:5)
  at async loadNuxt (node_modules/@nuxt/kit/dist/index.mjs:493:19)
  at async Object.invoke (node_modules/nuxi/dist/chunks/build.mjs:34:18)
  at async _main (node_modules/nuxi/dist/cli.mjs:50:20)
```

Answer (score 4):

The axios module is not something to use anymore for Nuxt3 as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74679190/8816585

Use `$fetch` directly, which is basically a wrapper around [ofetch](https://github.com/unjs/ofetch).

---

A quick way to see if a module is compatible with a specific version of Nuxt is to use the module page, for example here is the one [for axios](https://nuxt.com/modules?q=axios&version=3.x).
As you can see, it is not compatible with Nuxt3 since the page is empty.